# How to comparatively safely do the rollback when overwriting or deleting required

Tags: shell

I have a `backup` and `rollback` as follows:

#### backup

To ensure it's carried out successfully, I introduced a *flag* named `BACKED_UP`, which is initialized with value `0`.

```
function backup() {
    # used for back up and rollback
    FOLDER_DIR="xxxx";
    FOLDER_BAK_DIR="xxxx-bak";
    if [[ backupCondition ]]; then
        printStartMsg "Start to back up the old ...";
        mv ${FOLDER_DIR} "${FOLDER_BAK_DIR}";
        [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && BACKED_UP=1; 
        printEndMsg "${GREEN_SETTER}${FOLDER_DIR} backed up to ${BOLD_SETTER}${FOLDER_BAK_DIR}${COLOR_RESET}";
    fi
}
```

#### rollback

In the `rollback`, I will check the `BACKED_UP` flag and also the backup folder to ensure the backup exists and then remove the current existed folder.

```
function rollback() {
    if [[  ${BACKED_UP} -gt 0 && -d ${FOLDER_BAK_DIR}  ]]; then
        rm -rf ${FOLDER_DIR}; # this is dangerous
        printStartMsg "Rolling back now...";
        mv "${FOLDER_BAK_DIR}" ${FOLDER_DIR};
        printEndMsg "${GREEN_SETTER}Rolled back ${BOLD_SETTER}SUCCESSFULLY${COLOR_RESET}";
        exit 0;
    fi
}
```

#### my concerns

*The danger lies: the current existed folder `FOLDER_DIR` could be lost by `rm -rf`, worse still the backup is not complete.*

I know there are flaws, but otherwise what could be done here?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to take this approach, rather than a more robust and general solution (such as filesystem-level snapshots)?

Comment: Thanks, Charles, looking into it. Seems good to go :)

Answer (score 1):

It could be an overkill but how about using [dump](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dump), there are however *limitations* e.g [refer this from linus](http://lwn.net/2001/0503/a/lt-dump.php3)
but dump does a neat job of taking backups and managing those

Comment: thanks for the idea, I will also check it out for details.